# Multi Daemon Docker : How can I run a container on a specific Deamon?

Tags: docker

To fulfill the needs of my project, I need to have two Docker instances running on the same computer. I installed Docker on my Ubuntu operating system and followed the [tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#run-multiple-daemons) to create the second Docker instance. Now I would like to know:

1.I have used the below command to create a new daemon. is there  a command I can use to check the current statuses of both Docker instances?

```
 sudo dockerd \
    -H unix:///var/run/docker-bootstrap.sock \
    -p /var/run/docker-bootstrap.pid \
    --iptables=false \
    --ip-masq=false \
    --bridge=none \
    --data-root=/var/lib/docker-bootstrap \
    --exec-root=/var/run/docker-bootstrap
```

2.Once I execute the command mentioned earlier, will both daemons be running simultaneously?

3.When initiating a container, is it possible to assign them to a specific daemon? If yes, how can I make container *A* run on the default daemon and container *B* run on the new daemon?

I have searched on Stack Overflow and Docker tutorials, but I haven't come across any specific instructions for this. Additionally, it's worth noting that a single user will have access to both daemons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the `-H` (`--host`) option to tell the `docker` command line where to find the Docker engine API. If you have one Docker daemon listening on the standard `/var/run/docker.sock` and the second listening on `/var/run/docker-bootstrap.sock`, then:

> is there a command I can use to check the current statuses of both Docker instances?

You can run `docker info` to query the Docker daemon listening on the standard socket, and `docker -H unix:///var/run/docker-bootstrap.sock info` to query the daemon running on the alternate socket.

> Once I execute the command mentioned earlier, will both daemons be running simultaneously?

If you have started the Docker daemon on the standard socket and you run your `sudo dockerd ...` command, then both daemons will be  running.

> When initiating a container, is it possible to assign them to a specific daemon?

Sure, use the `-H` option we discussed earlier. To run a container on the standard socket:

```
docker run ...
```

And on your alternate socket:

```
docker -H unix:///var/run/docker-bootstrap.sock run ...
```

---

If you get tired of typing `-H unix:///var/run/docker-bootstrap.sock` all the time, you can define multiple Docker [contexts](https://docs.docker.com/engine/context/working-with-contexts/):

You should already have a `default` context (list with `docker context ls`). You can create an alternate context with the `docker context create` command:

```
docker context create bootstrap --docker host=unix:///var/run/docker-bootstrap.sock
```

Now you can select the "bootstrap" Docker daemon like this:

```
docker context use bootstrap
```

After this, commands like `docker ps`, `docker run`, etc, will use the bootstrap socket. To return to the default socket:

```
docker context use default
```

---

> I ran a Container named C1 on my default docker. When I want to use it on my bootstrap docker with the same name, I got error. When I have two different daemon, Why I cannot run a container with same name seperately on each of them?

I can't reproduce that problem.

I've started a second Docker daemon like this:

```
dockerd \
    -H unix:///var/run/docker-bootstrap.sock \
    -p /var/run/docker-bootstrap.pid \
    --iptables=false \
    --ip-masq=false \
    --bridge=docker1 \
    --data-root=/var/lib/docker-bootstrap \
    --exec-root=/var/run/docker-bootstrap
```

Note that I'm using `--bridge=docker1` instead of `--bridge=none`, because I found that with `--bridge=none` the second Docker daemon would **remove** the existing `docker0` bridge.

With both this daemon and the original daemon running, I can start two containers with the same name, one in each Docker instance:

```
docker run --name container1 --rm -d alpine sleep 300
docker -H unix:///var/run/docker-bootstrap.sock run --name container1 --rm -d alpine sleep 300
```

We can query running containers in the default instance:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND       CREATED          STATUS          PORTS     NAMES
bc471852c22d   alpine    "sleep 300"   19 seconds ago   Up 18 seconds             container1
```

And in the "bootstrap" instance:

```
$ docker -H unix:///var/run/docker-bootstrap.sock ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND       CREATED          STATUS          PORTS     NAMES
7ef210c599f5   alpine    "sleep 300"   43 seconds ago   Up 43 seconds             container1
```

Note that the above output shows two different containers ids, but both with the same name.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just one last question, I ran a Container named C1 on my default docker. When I want to use it on my bootstrap docker with the same name, I got error. When I have two different daemon, Why I cannot run a container with same name seperately on each of them?

Comment: I've updated my answer to address your comment.